# Poisson equation in polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, poissons-equation

I am having trouble finding a solution to the poisson equation:
$\frac{∂^2u}{∂r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{∂u}{dr}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{∂^2u}{∂θ^2}=-r^2\sin2\theta$
with $a<r<b$, $-π<θ<π$ and $\frac{∂u}{∂r}(a,θ) = \frac{∂u}{∂r}(b,θ) = 0$.
I have tried assuming that the solution is $(kr^4+lr^3+mr^2+nr+p)\sin2\theta$ and replacing in the equation but this solution doesn't satisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: Have you studied the case when both $u$ and the r.h.s are independent of $\theta$? This will help you I believe.

Comment: @Joce I don't know if I completely understood what you mean. In rhs there is $θ$ how can this be independent of $θ$?

Comment: I was suggesting to change r.h.s too to start with. This would have allowed you to find by yourself that the solution includes negative powers of $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption $\quad (kr^4+lr^3+mr^2+nr+p)\sin2\theta\quad $ is too restrictive. Assume :
$$u=f(r)\sin(2\theta)$$
Putting it into $\quad \frac{∂^2u}{∂r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{∂u}{dr}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{∂^2u}{∂θ^2}=-r^2\sin2\theta\quad $ leads to :
$$f''+\frac{1}{r}f'-\frac{4}{r^2}f=-r^2$$
The solution of this linear ODE is :
$$f(r)= -\frac{1}{12}r^4+c_1r^2+c_2r^{-2}$$
$$u(r,\theta)=\left(-\frac{1}{12}r^4+c_1r^2+c_2r^{-2}\right)\sin(2\theta)$$
$$\frac{∂u}{dr}(r,\theta)=\left(-\frac{1}{3}r^3+2c_1r-2c_2r^{-3}\right)\sin(2\theta)$$
The conditions $\quad\frac{∂u}{∂r}(a,θ) = \frac{∂u}{∂r}(b,θ) = 0\quad$ implies :
$$\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{3}a^3+2c_1a-2c_2a^{-3}=0 \\
-\frac{1}{3}b^3+2c_1b-2c_2b^{-3}=0
\end{cases}$$
To be solved for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder how I hadn't thought that